# SSH connection to MySQL using SSH.NET library

Tags: c#, mysql, database, ssh, connection-string

I was given a link to use this library for connection through SSH connection to a MySQL database with C#.

Here is the [LINK](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/) to the library as a lot of you will find this interesting as you don't need to open a SSH channel manually.

This is a very detailed library and has a lot of features but what I want to do is pretty simple. I just want to open a SSH channel each time I want to write to the database.

While I was searching through the source that is provided I came up to this part of the code which can be found in **TestSshCommand.cs** and I think I can use this part for my connections but I need your help to get it work as I have my connection string I don't know how to connect all of it.

Code:

```
public void Test_Execute_SingleCommand()
        {
            using (var client = new SshClient(Resources.HOST, Resources.USERNAME, Resources.PASSWORD))
            {
                client.Connect();
                var result = ExecuteTestCommand(client);
                client.Disconnect();

                Assert.IsTrue(result);
            }
```

My code for connectiong to non SSH channel is:

```
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con2"].ConnectionString;
            con.Open();
            cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + ConfigSettings.ReadSetting("main"), con);

     //...... more of the code
```

So how can I combine this code to the above one so it can first open a SSH channel and then execute my query?

Do I need to put my code inside *connect* and *disconnect* functions?

One more think I have add **.dll** file inside references and I must say that none of the imports are working. So can someone please download the library and try this simple code to see if references are working on your project and so that everyone ( which are a lot ) can have a working solution for their future projects?

EDIT:

This is my code that I was trying to do later on. My SSH connection works now only need to combine those two to get it work.

Problem is that I need to have one database locally on my pc and need to connect to the server. So port forwarding won't work as somone says on the forum that I can't port forward while mysql already have port for running

```
using (var client = new SshClient("cpanel****", "******", "******"))
          {
            client.Connect();
            con = new MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            con.Open();
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(String.Format("insert into {0} values (null, ?Parname , ?Parname2, ?Parname3, ?Parname4, ?Parname5, ?Parname6, ?Parname7);", ConfigSettings.ReadSetting("main")), con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("?Parname", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = Math.Round(deciLat, 5);
            // ... more parameters
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            client.Disconnect();
           }
```

Comment: You probably should use library to forward remote to local port and use that in your connection string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to setup port forwarding with your SSH connection...

Basically make a SSH connection that listens on port 3306 on localhost and forwards that to your MySQL DB server...

In the connections string to your MySQL DB you need to change the part `server=...` to `server=localhost` while your SSH connection needs to go to your MySQL DB server's IP.

IF you can't forward port 3306 you can use any port you want BUT you need change the additionally the `port=` part of the connection string... see [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql) for examples on connection strings with a different port... the SSH connection still targets 3306 but listens on a different port on localhost in this case...

Here are some working examples with source code (although not with SSH.NET since I don't use SSH.NET but this should nonetheless get you started IMO):

- http://georgelantz.com/2007/09/10/access-mysql-through-ssh-tunnel-in-a-windows-net-application/
- http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/access-your-mysql-server-remotely-over-ssh/ (this is just an option on how to use a local SSH client from commandline to set this up)

Comment: hi, thank you for your try but I already tried all of this. Please read my question all the way. I wrote about port forwarding

Comment: I just need to combine SSH.NET as I am passing a SSH connection

Comment: @denonth you can't use any SSH connection... the SSH connection MUST be setup as a port forwarding connection AND you need to change your MySQL connection string - otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @denonth IF you can't forward port 3306 you can use any port you want BUT you need change the additionally the `port=` part of the connection string...

Comment: I have tried your app on the first link. I can't get authentication, I even wrote the post at the bottow of that page. I put a local port as 3307 as I am using a 3306 but I can't get auth. Btw. somone told me that I can't have a local port on 3306 that will have local database and forwarded port on 3307 as this 2 won't work together. I need a local db and server one. I don't wont to use php as I need fast saving every 5-7 sec

Comment: @denonth you are saying that you want to have 2 DB servers (one localhost, one remote)... which one do you want to connect to exactly ?

Comment: So let me be more specific. I have 2 connection strings. One has reference on the local database and other conn string has reference on real network server.  Reason why I have those two servers is that I am checking if I have a internet connection and if there is no internet connection I start to save data to local server which doesn't need anything of it. So my problem right now is how to connect to a real network server which has firewall as I didn't expecting to have one. I wrote my code and it should already be done but this stoped me for some time.

Comment: SSH tunnel must be made from the code as this is a self start app which do everything automatically ( no user needed)

Comment: @denonth then you need to run your local MySQL server on different port... this way 3306 is free for forwarding...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12026/discussion-between-denonth-and-yahia)

Comment: Hi I have tried and changed port of my localdatabase to 3307 now when I try to port forward to 3306 I get some auth error. What type of database name should be on my port forwarding?

Comment: Can you help me with step by step on the chat with this?

Comment: I got it to work. you were right, now I have a port local on 3307 and remote on 3306. Thank you

Comment: I can give you bounty reward in 22h so wait a bit. I have upovoted you and accepted answer

Comment: @denonth I was in a meeting and just came back... glad that you got it to work :-)

Answer (score 8):

You simply need to use a different local port for the tunnel than 3306 which is being used by your MySQL instance.

Example below with port 8001 being used instead:

```
using (var client = new SshClient("ssh_hostname", "ssh_username", "ssh_password"))
{
  client.Connect();
  var tunnel = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", 8001, "127.0.0.1", 3306);
  client.AddForwardedPort(tunnel);
  tunnel.Start();
  using (var DB = new DBContext())
  {
    //MySQL interaction here!
    scores = DB.Table
      .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SomeField))
      .ToList();
  }
  tunnel.Stop();
}
```

And then make sure in your connection string you have the server 127.0.0.1 and the port 8001

```
server=127.0.0.1;port=8001
```

This will connect anything going to 127.0.0.1:8001 to ssh_hostname:3306.

Comment: This works perfectly, ty very much. Although, is it neccesary to open it each time? Can I open only once?